# Can Matlab send detailed orders to 7-Zip?

Tags: matlab, 7zip

I need to make the smallest compressions I can of many pairs of files - 100 at the moment, and many more in the future.
If there's a toolbox by which I can command Matlab to tell 7-Zip to compress these files with these settings, that would be optimal. (I'm using Matlab to create these files.) But though I searched on Stack Overflow, did some googling and searched for "7-Zip" on the Mathworks Community and Documentation, I found nothing promising.

Is there some way I could execute a command like

```
for ii = 1:100
    7zCompress(['data',num2str(ii),'a.csv'],['data',num2str(ii),'b.csv'],'7z','Ultra','LZMA2','1024MB',273,'Solid',8)
end
```

?

(The first two arguments, in square brackets, are the files I want compressed together, and the rest are the settings I select on 7-Zip.)

Comment: This can be done with the `system` function. Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

Comment: just try to find out how to control 7zip in batch mode from the command line and then call the cmd from Matlab.

Comment: @MingjingZhang - Thanks, that helped!

Comment: One thing I needed to do before it did work, however, was to modify the path to include the folder containing `7z.exe`. And it turned out that there are multiple paths that can be modified. `system('PATH = %PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\')` did nothing, modifying Matlab's path did nothing. I had to google "matlab windows system modify path" and click [modify windows system path](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-set-my-system-path-under-windows) to learn that the path I need to change is part of the Windows settings.

Should I make this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, call the Matlab function *`system()`* combining the commands via *&&* in following way:

**1)** to make an archive in a certain folder:

```
[status,cmdout] = system('C: && cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip && 7z.exe a -t7z -mx8 d:\test\archive.7z d:\test\archive.txt');
```

**where:**
*`status`*   - returned code of execution status;
*`cmdout`*   - returned message from the command line (useful to execution control & debug);
*`C:`*   - set C: as current disk;
*`cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip`*   - set the 7Zip installation folder as current;
*`7z.exe`*   - call 7Zip with parameters:
*`a`*   - make the archive;
*`-t7z`*   - set type of the archive as 7Zip;
*`-mx8`*   - set the compression level as Maximum;
*`d:\test\archive.7z`*   - file name of the future archive;
*`d:\test\archive.txt`*   - name of the file to be archived;

**2)** to extract an archive to a certain folder:

```
[status,cmdout] = system('C: && cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip && 7z.exe x d:\test\archive.7z -od:\test\');
```

**where:**
*`status`*   - returned code of execution status;
*`cmdout`*   - returned message from the command line (useful to execution control & debug);
*`C:`*   - set C: as current disk;
*`cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip`*   - set the 7Zip installation folder as current;
*`7z.exe`*   - call 7Zip with parameters:
*`x`*   - extract the archive from the certain folder;
*`d:\test\archive.7z`*   - file name of the archive;
*`-od:\test\`*   - extract to folder d:\test\ .